# in installing Ubuntu facing problem with following message "serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /"

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

As i installed latest ubuntu 14.04 in my windows 7 'D' drive after reboot it showing following message
serious errors were found while checking  the disk drive for / .

i re installed ubuntu for confirmation but still facing same problem.
 what to do now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that GRUB is looking for your `/` partition in the wrong place, or failed to install at all. In order to diagnose your problem, you will want to use `boot-repair`. Since you have an Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB, it is most convenient to run the utility from there. Instructions on doing so can be found [at the Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu), but a brief synopsis can be found below.

1. Boot into your LiveCD/LiveUSB
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu"
3. Establish an Internet connection. Note that this is different from a network connection in that you need to be able to connect to a website as well.
4. Open the Terminal application from your Dash. If you are having trouble finding your Dash, try typing just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
5. Enter the command, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`. Be sure to follow this with a carriage return (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) so it can execute.
6. Enter the command, `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)` after it finishes executing, and be sure to execute this one as well.
7. Select "Recommended Repair".
8. When the repair is finished, copy down the URL you are provided with. If your repair does not work, this will be necessary for further troubleshooting.
9. Reboot your computer normally (i.e. not to your installation media).
10. Now, you should be able to boot to Ubuntu. If that is not the case, please update your question with the URL you copied down earlier.